# Search box microformat?

Tags: html, web-standards, microformats

Is there any microformat/standard for implementing search form on the site?
(access keys, naming etc.)

Any good practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only things I can think of are that searches should be GET requests, and that you may want to implement a RESTful API that allows developers to query JSON and XML results in addition to HTML

If you are trying to implement a plugin for browsers like IE and Firefox to allow for search/autocomplete in the search box of the browser, check out this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/creating_opensearch_plugins_for_firefox

Answer (score 0):

Here are some conventions I follow. Forgive me if these are not exactly on topic with microformats, or "technically not" in the way I describe the various parts to my answer.

I have found validation in these few standards I've copied from others:

HTML form `ID = "search"`

Action URL for the form is `//root-of-site/search/`

Search Results URL construct:

```
//root-of-site/search?q=queryClause1+Clause2&AnotherParamName=foo
```

[personally that structure bugs me a little because search-forward-slash appears to be a directory, and the search-question-mark looks like a page taking a query string, and IMO a page should have a suffix. I've been tempted to use search.cgi or search.app, but I see the big guys using /search?q= and so it is]

ID of search query is "q" (this is nearly universal in adoption)

Comment: Why does a page need a suffix? They are bloat. IMO the presence of the final slash determines whether the URL refers to a document or an index.

Comment: I understand your point, but to me, the final slash just implies the preceding string (between the slashes) is a directory. With no filename requested, *traditionally* the web server loads the default document per its rules for that *directory* (such as index.html or default.html). Certainly, we have the tools to serve it up regardless of the way it's written, but to me, the conventions of old carry much weight. Long ago, I used to save documents on a Mac (OS 6+) with a suffix because it added value. I tend to think it still does... add value. I suppose I shouldn't say it "bugs me." :)

Comment: I disagree with you there.  Adding a .php extension to the end of a file doesn't add any value.  Whether I know a page is written in php or not doesn't affect me in any way.  The more modern RESTful way of doing things makes the few times an extension is included matter.  Now I can add .json or .xml to the end of a URL and receive the results in a new format that I can plug into another application/service.  This is the actual value added.

Comment: @Wade, good illustration. What you're saying is that it would be nice to interpret the suffix to determine what to return? I like that. You could send .html, .json, .xml (+ others within reason, I suppose) depending upon the suffix requested. That's cool. I think that our differences here come from my desire to retain much of the original (old school) URL semantics, but we have really moved on to URI strings and the old paradigm is just not necessary. [but I think that still perhaps assumed... ] :)

Comment: Yeah, it really just takes spending some time to understand RESTful development and ways of doing things. The other advantage to this way of working is that because the layout of a site isn't tied to an actual directory structure, you can have a site that is SEO friendly very easily.  http://www.example.com/user/wadetandy/bio can easily be translated to a database query for username = 'wadetandy' but it allows things to be expressed in a cleaner way.  Most modern web frameworks support all of these features in a very accessible way.